# Npgsql EF Core concatenation expression

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a `customer` table with columns `firstname`, `lastname` and a trigram index:

`CREATE INDEX ix_customer_search_trgm ON customer USING gin ((firstname || lastname ) gin_trgm_ops);"`

I'm trying to search customers by firstname or lastname using C#/EFCore but can't figure out how to specify a concatenation expression for `firstname || lastname`

I tried the following

1. `dbContext.Customers.Where(q => EF.Functions.ILike('firstname || lastname', $"%{searchTerm}%"));`
   This generates a query like below (notice `$1 = 'f'` which looks odd) and doesn't match the columns

```
2020-12-01 23:04:52.119 AEDT [38091] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT ...
        FROM customer AS c
        WHERE $1

2020-12-01 23:04:52.119 AEDT [38091] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'f'
```

2. `dbContext.Customers.Where(q => EF.Functions.ILike(q.firstname, $"%{searchTerm}%"));`
   This generates the sort of query I expect but obviously filters only one of the columns in the expression.

```
2020-12-01 23:02:21.777 AEDT [38034] LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT ...
        FROM customer AS c
        WHERE c.customer ILIKE $1 ESCAPE ''
2020-12-01 23:02:21.777 AEDT [38034] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '%abc%'
```

How can I specify a concatenation expression for the above with EF Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all other EF Core LINQ methods, ILike doesn't accept a raw SQL string which gets integrated into the query, but rather a .NET expression which EF Core translates for you. So you should be able to achieve the above with:

```cs
dbContext.Customers.Where(q => EF.Functions.ILike(q.FirstName + q.LastName, $"%{searchTerm}%"));
~~~
```

Comment: Thanks @Shay this works! Can you explain how it works just for my curiosity (since you know all about the internals ;) - I'd have thought that at runtime `ILike` would receive the value of the expression (i.e. concatenated firstname + lastname) as usual with function args but how does it figure out it should generate a postgres specific syntax based on the `+` operator?

Comment: Well, ILike isn't different from anything else in an EF LINQ query... EF receives an expression tree representation of your query (where the call the ILike is just a node in the tree), and then translates that tree to the right SQL expression. ILike is never actually invoked in .NET (it has no actual implementation in .NET - it just throws). This is the same as anything else you put in a Where clause (e.g. Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith("A")).